# The lightest Pixel

Tags: c, arrays, pixel

It shouldn't be too difficult to look through pixels in a (decoded) png file to figure out which one is the darkest and which is the lightest, but for whatever reason, when I filter through a BLACK AND WHITE image of Chris Hadfield, my function tells me the lightest pixel is that of value 74, which is a dark grey when there are clearly many pearly white pixels, my method should spit out 255. I have an opposite c method as well fro the darkest value and I get 0 as expected, but what could be wrong with my code. Answers would be appreciated. In testing, I set lightest to 255, so it is impossible for any pixel to be lighter than that, and my code still spits on 74. What's the deal?

```
uint8_t min( const uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows )  {

    uint8_t darkest = 255;

    for(int pixel = 0; pixel < (cols * rows); pixel++){
        if(array[pixel] < darkest){
            darkest = array[pixel]; }}

  return darkest;
}

/* Return the lightest color that appears in the array; i.e. the
   largest value
*/

uint8_t max( const uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows )    {

    int8_t lightest = 0;

    for(int pixel = 0; pixel < (cols * rows); pixel++){
        if(array[pixel] > lightest){
            lightest = array[pixel]; }}

    return lightest;
}
```

Comment: Beware of signed integers here. Try `uint8_t` throughout.

Comment: 255 in `int8_t` is -1. Don't you get a warning on `array[pixel] > lightest`?

Comment: @Arkadiy: Due to promotions, that will end up being `int > int`, which is fine, no warning.

Comment: I have since solved this problem, I blinked and realised that in fact my lightest was the wrong data type, should have been uint8_t. thank you

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: I incorrectly typed int8_t lightest as opposed to uint8_t. I noticed a few minute after posting this, silly me

Comment: @zubergu: Except that `lightest` doesn't stay 0 forever, does it?

Comment: well, I printed a value in the loop before my fix, and negative numbers were abundant, which is impossible for an array that is full of unsigned ints. I changed the data type of lightest and upon printing, the values were positive? And 255 was the lightest value as expected. Not sure why this was, but my problem is solved @Ed S. was on the right track

Answer (score 0):

The assigned value of lightest was incorrect. It should be uint8_t, the unsigned version of this data type.